How to read a file that is given from NodeJS to a c++ process using stdin?
I created a C++ program that uses a method of a library. This method needs an istream to work.
The C++ compiled program is executed using child_process module of NodeJS and the file is sent to the c++ process using stdin.
How could I retrieve the given file into an istream ?
Here is what I've tried but it didn't work:
C++ script:
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    cout << "\n---------------- STL TO PRIMITIVE ----------------\n" << endl;
    auto beg = chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

    // Retrieve the buffer of the STL file
    std::istream &input_stream = std::cin;

    const double mv = 2;
    const double min_threshold = 0.1;
    const unsigned int depth = 7;
    string method = "threshold";
    Mesh mesh;

    // Read the STL file
    cout << "~ Reading STL file..." << endl;
    if (!CGAL::IO::read_STL(input_stream, mesh))
    {
        cout << "ERROR WHILE READING THE FILE" << endl;
    }
}

NodeJS script:
const { spawn } = require("child_process");
const fs = require("fs");

const fileContent = fs.readFileSync("./PipedPBase.stl");

const process = spawn('../MeshReshaper/build/release/MeshReshaper',{ stdio: ['pipe', 'inherit', 'inherit'] });

process.stdin.write(fileContent.toString());
process.stdin.end();

process.stderr.on('data', data => {
    console.log("ERROR -> " + data);
})

process.on('close', code => {
    console.log("Closed with code " + code);
});


If the output from node is sent through standard input, then just read from std::cin as usual. That's how pipes normally works.

You... didn't do anything on the C++ side, what did you expect? Are you asking how to read from standard input?

@PasserBy I do not want people to focus on what I will do with the file in my c++ code. I just want to know how to store the file that is given from my NodeJS code through the stdin into an istream. Sorry if it was not so clear ^^'

You said "it didn't work", but without any code we have no idea how exactly it didn't work. For all we know, you're missing a semicolon somewhere and can't compile your program. Please read [mre].

Yes, my bad. The file is well passed but it seems that there is changes into it and so the function that uses the istream doesn't work properly. I'll edit my post to add the real code I use. Sorry for that

What is the actual data being sent? Is it binary or text? If it's binary then it could be a problem with newline translations. Either in the node script, in the reading in the C++ program, or in the writing to the destination file.

It is a STL binary file @Someprogrammerdude

Is this on windows? If so you need to call some extra functions to pass binary data through stdin

No, I use linux.

Buffer#toString is documented as using UTF-8 when no encoding is specified. This absolutely wrecks binary files.
Just do process.stdin.write(fileContent) instead. Better still, use the pipe method of an open stream to have node.js pipe data for you.
